# Find the derivative of $^{x\sin(/)}$ at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am not sure what the correct answer is and I am stuck on a problem. I will list the question below and provide my reasoning. Please let me know where or if there is something incorrect in my process. Here is the question:

Consider the function

$$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    xe^{x\sin \big( \frac{\pi}{x} \big)} & \text{if } x\neq 0\\
    0              & \text{if } x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$

Determine $f'(0)$. Write DNE if the derivative is not defined.
(Note: The expression in the exponent is $x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$.)

**My reasoning**

To show that $f$ is differentiable at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we must show that $f'(x)$ exists at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Recall that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if $\lim_{x\to h} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ exists.

The derivative at $x=0$ is given by the limit:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{he^{h\sin \big( \frac{\pi}{h} \big)} - 0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h\sin \big( \frac{\pi}{h} \big)}$$

Now the range of sine is also [−1, 1], so

$$-1 \leq \sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{h} \Big) \leq 1 $$

Taking $e^{h}$ raised to both sides of an inequality does not change the inequality, so
$$(e^{h})^{-1} \leq (e^{h})^{\sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{h} \Big)} \leq (e^{h})^{1} $$

$$e^{-h} \leq e^{h\sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{h} \Big)} \leq e^{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0} e^{-h} \leq \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h\sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{h} \Big)} \leq \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h}$$

So, our original function is bounded by $e^{-h}$ and $e^{h}$, and since

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} e^{-h} = \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h} = 1$$

Then, by squeeze theorem,

$$\lim_{h\to 0} e^{h\sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{h} \Big)} = 1. $$

So, $f'(0) = 1$.

When look up the limit on a calculator, I find $\lim_{h\to 0} e^{h\sin \big( \frac{\pi}{h} \big)} = $ DNE.

The answer key said $f'(0) = 0$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: At least in principle your answer seems correct. Definition and algebra certainly line up. Squeeze theorem clearly works out to your result just by looking at [some graphs](https://i.imgur.com/o6eSomc.png). Though hardly meaningful, looking at [a graph](https://i.imgur.com/skN7R5T.png) of the function it just feels like it is begging to be said to have derivative $1$ near $0$. Yet Desmos' [graph of the derivative](https://i.imgur.com/lBgCg9s.png) seems very poorly behaved. ... I wonder if the reason is just due to numerical errors for $\pi/x$ at $x \approx 0$.

Comment: No clue how one concludes $0$ as the answer... Now ***I'm*** wondering if I'm the crazy one and overlooking something.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BPower%5Be%2Cxsin%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bpi%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx-%3E0%5D

Comment: Your proof is fine. The answer key probably meant to say $f'(0)=e^0$.

Comment: Your inequalities are satisfied for $h>0.$ You should use $|h|$ to get correct inequalities for general case.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct. The answer key was outdated and meant to say: $$f'(0) = e^{0}.$$